# Is it possible to answer to an facebook event using an app?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook

Is it possible to answer to an event using facebook connect, by calling the method requestwithgraphpath like this:

```
[[Facebook shared] requestWithGraphPath:link/attending andParams:params2 andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

What about changing the answer? (Do I have to call "DELETE" to attending and then call "POST" to maybe or declined ?)

I am using the permissions rsvp_event and user_events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/560/) here from when the API was last updated with an example of some of the API calls, the main docs are at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Basically, to remove a user from the event it's a `DELETE` to `/{event id}/invited` - this one  may require the 'create_event' permission as it's a modification to the event, i'm not 100% sure.

To change RSVP status it's a `POST` to `/{event id}/{status}` where `{status}` is one of attending, maybe, declined

Comment: {eventid}/attanding gives me all event attanding person list but not seting user stataus to attanding